# Is there a way to prevent an Mddialog widget from closing?

Tags: python, dismiss, mddialog

I make a box that appears when I click on a button. I want it to closed only when I click on the buttons that are displayed on that box. But it's still closed when I click somewhere else.

I make an interface that contains a button. And when I click on the button it open a box that contains 3 buttons. I created this box using a kivymd Mddialog widget. When I click on one of these 3 buttons it dismiss the box. But the problem is that when I click somewhere else, the box is also dismissed.  So I want the box to be dismissed only when I click on the the buttons that are displayed in the box, and to keep open when I click somewhere else.

Here is my python code

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp 

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 

from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen

from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager 

from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout 

from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog

from kivymd.uix.button import MDFloatingActionButton,MDFlatButton,MDRoundFlatButton

ref_help=None

class Interface(MDScreen):

    def show_help(self):

        global ref_help

        ref_help=Help()

        ref_help.open()

        

class Help(MDDialog):

    def close_help(self):

        global ref_help

        ref_help.dismiss()

class MyApp(MDApp):

    pass

MyApp().run()
```

```
Et voici le code kv

Interface:

<Interface>:

    MDScreen:

        name:"screen1"

        MDRoundFlatButton:

            id: start_button

            text:"START"

            font_size:70

            pos_hint:{"center_x":.5,"center_y":.22}

            on_press: root.show_help()

        

            

Here is the kV code

            

<Help>:

    md_bg_color:0,0,0,0

    radius:[dp(30),dp(30),dp(30),dp(30)]

    size_hint:.8,.2

    MDBoxLayout:

        radius:[dp(30),dp(30),dp(30),dp(30)]

        md_bg_color:1,1,0,.1

        orientation: "vertical"

        

        MDLabel:

            text:"help center"

            font_size: dp(30)

            halign:"center"

            pos_hint:{"top":1}

        

        MDBoxLayout:

            spacing: dp(5)

            pos_hint:{"center_x":.5}

            padding:dp(40),dp(1)

            

            MDIconButton:

                id: delete

                theme_text_color:"Custom"

                text_color:1,0,0,1

                icon:"delete"

                icon_size:dp(40)

                on_press: root.close_help()

            MDIconButton:

                id: equal

                theme_text_color:"Custom"

                text_color:1,0,0,1

                icon:"approximately-equal"

                icon_size:dp(40)

                on_press: root.close_help()

            MDIconButton:

                id: wifi

                theme_text_color:"Custom"

                text_color:1,0,0,1

                icon:"wifi"

                icon_size:dp(40)

                on_press: root.close_help()
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed the issues. In kivymd there is a property inside the Mddialog that called auto_dismiss. By default this property is set to True. In order to avoid the Mddialog to be closed when you click somewhere else you just have to turn this property into False.